# Stopping a function in a for loop python

Tags: python, function

I'm having problems with stopping a function whilst inside a for loop.

```
def character(char_type,word,number):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        for e in range(len(char_type)):
            if word[i]==char_type[e]:
                if char_type==vowels:
                    number[0]=number[0]+1
                elif char_type==consonants:
                    number[1]=number[1]+1
                elif char_type==valid_symbols:
                    number=number
            else:
                number=[-1,-1]
```

I need the function to terminate if number=[-1,-1] but can't figure out how to do it. I have tried using return at every level of indentation but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `== != =` ...... (but `return` does terminate the function)

Comment: `return` definitely does stop a function. But `number==[-1,-1]` doesn't do anything useful. Assignment is `=`, not `==`.

Comment: for better readiblity, you should think about using `pass` if you don't want to do anything in one `elif`.

Comment: Or drop the redundant `elif` entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your char_type is a dictionary having values

char_type = { 'a': 'vowels', 'b' : 'consonants', .....}

You can manipulate your code like this

```
   def character(char_type,word,number):

       for i in word:   #using range(len(word)) is a bad practice, you can directly access each character from a word

          if i in char_type.keys():

             if char_type[i] == vowels:
                number[0] = number[0]+1

             elif char_type[i] == consonants:
                number[1] = number[1]+1

             elif char_type[i] == valid_symbols:
                pass

         else:
            number=[-1,-1]
            break
```

Likewise, there are several ways one can write a logic for this. Currently, this is the one I can think of. Hope this works for you :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use *break* statement and also check this [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm).